# Shiny calculate the mean of columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, mean

I'm trying to calculate the mean of all columns in a data frame but I get the error :  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.
Here's the code I'm using:

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

#library(data.table)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))


  ),
  mainPanel(

    tableOutput('data'),
    verbatimTextOutput('mean')

  )
))
```

**server.UI**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$data <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    data<-data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=FALSE, sep=";"))

  })
  output$mean<-renderPrint({

   mean(data)

  })
})
```

I'm completely lost and I can't figure out the error. please help me. thanks.

Comment: I haven't looked through your code thoroughly, but you're trying to take the mean of a `data.frame` object. Looking `?mean` it shows that that function is not supported for data frames. If you want a specific column mean try `mean(data$MY_COL)`

Comment: It still not working.. is there any other way to calculate the mean of a dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by the mean of a data frame? Do you want the mean of every value in the data frame? Do you want the mean of every column? Every row? Something else? What do you plan to do with categorical variables? Dates? Other non-numeric values?

Comment: I want the mean of every column, exept the column containing dates

Comment: How about `lapply(data, function(x) {if(is.numeric(x)) return(mean(x); return(NA)})`.

Comment: can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so your main problem si that you're trying to take the mean of a data frame, which is not possible using the `mean()` function. This code should work (note since you didn't give any example data I made some up - I threw in a date column in there and the function doesn't take the mean of it).

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    #Change the below line
    data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,4,5),c=as.Date(c("12/31/09","12/31/10","12/31/11"),"%m/%d/%y"))

  })

  output$mean<-renderPrint({

   colMeans(dataset()[,which(sapply(dataset(), class) != "Date")])

  })
})
```

Note that I call `dataset()` which allows me to reference the data. This should give you your expected output. Note that I also call the `colMeans` function on all the columns in the dataset that are not of the type `Date`. You should also be able to substitute your dataframe definition for mine. That is, in my code you would just replace `data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,4,5),c=as.Date(c("12/31/09","12/31/10","12/31/11"),"%m/%d/%y"))` with your code in your `renderTable()` call.

Hope this helps.

*EDIT:* Per comments below, it turns out you can can define your data in the `renderTable` call and reference it in the `renderPrint`. The two main problems were the definition of the data in the `read.csv()` and the attempt to call `mean` on dataframe. The latter problem is fixed by `colMeans()` and the former was fixed using code from @Mouna : `dataset<-data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep = ";", dec = ","))`

Comment: thank you @mikeyMike for your clarifications, but I'm afraid it still not working, there is still a problem in  `colMeans(dataset()[,which(sapply(df, class) != "Date")])` even with the data frame you created..

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to change some code. Should be fixed now, let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you so much @mikeyMike it's working ! the problem I had was in the file.csv, so I had to change `read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=FALSE, sep=";")`with `dataset<-data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep = ";", dec = ","))` .

Comment: Glad I could help out. I'm relatively new to shiny and didn't actually know you could reference data from `renderPrint`. Feel free to click the check box next to my answer if you thought it was helpful!

Comment: Done. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mean of each column of a data frame by using '**colMeans(.)**' command. It returns a vector whose each element is the mean of each column in your data frame.