# Calculate mean and median by date range in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt, reactive, shiny-reactivity

Want to calculate mean and median of the numeric variables grouped by a selected date range for the datatable only, not the leaflet data. The leaflet map works (just need to zoom out to see the fake long/lat plots but not worried about that now).

I created a second dataframe `df10` for the datatable median/mean summations of the data.

So far tried altering the input function to create separate variables for the mean but found it to be cumbersome and not necessary for my needs.

Attempted to use `colMeans(dataset()[,which(sapply(dataset(), class) != "Date")])` here [Shiny calculate the mean of columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333825/shiny-calculate-the-mean-of-columns-in-dataframe)

The error is `"invalid 'x' type in 'x && y"`. It's in relation to the colmeans

```
### Generate a dataset ###
start_date <- as.Date('2018-01-01')  
end_date <- as.Date('2019-05-10')   
set.seed(1984)
date1 <- as.Date(sample( as.numeric(start_date): as.numeric(end_date), 988, 
                         replace = T), origin = '1970-01-01')
group <- rep(letters[1:26], each = 38)
x1 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x2 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x3 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x4 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x5 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
latitude <- runif(988,40.75042,50.75042)
longitude <- runif(988,-73.98928,-63.98928)

dataframe <- cbind(data.frame(date1,group,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,latitude,longitude))

df10 <- cbind(data.frame(date1,group,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5))
library(lubridate)
dataframe$date <- ymd(dataframe$date1)
df10$date <- ymd(df10$date1)

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
dataframe$defectrateLvl <- cut(dataframe$x1, 
                               c(3.26,6,100), include.lowest = T,
                               labels = c('3.26-6x','6x+')) 
beatCol <- colorFactor(palette = c('yellow', 'red'), dataframe$defectrateLvl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput(inputId = "date", label="Select a date", value = "2019-03-01", min = "2018-01-01", max = "2019-05-10",
            format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month",
            language = "en", width = NULL),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  fluidRow(
    dateRangeInput("daterange","Date range:",start=Sys.Date()-10, end=Sys.Date() -1),
    DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function (input, output,session) {
  dailyData <- reactive(dataframe[dataframe$date == format(input$date, '%Y/%m/%d'), ] )
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    dataframe <- dailyData()  # Added this in attempt to integrate
    dataframe %>% leaflet() %>% 
      setView(lng = -73.98928, lat = 40.75042, zoom = 10) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng=~dataframe$longitude, # Longitude coordinates
        lat=~dataframe$latitude, # Latitude coordinates
        #radius=~defectrateLvl, # Total count
        popup =~ dataframe$group,
        color = ~beatCol(dataframe$defectrateLvl),
        fillOpacity=0.5 # Circle Fill Opacity
      )
  })  
  output$tbl<-DT::renderDataTable({
    dataset <- reactive({df10 })
    dataset() %>% group_by(group) %>% 
      filter(date > input$daterange[1],
             date < input$daterange[2])
    #sapply(Filter(is.numeric, df6), mean)
    colMeans(dataset()[,which(sapply(dataset(), class) !="date","date1","group")])
  })

})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expect to have the numeric variables to be summarized by mean and if possible by median but that's less important at this time.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please fix your code, there are multiple errors in it. Bracket errors, missing datasets (df7 for example)

Comment: your code still does not work. Missing commata and brackets left...

Comment: @DSGym I updated the code. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: thank you, it worked now. Does the solution help you?

Comment: @DSGym yes it did. Thank you! Just curious if I could use the ```result2 <- data.frame(colMedians(df[which(sapply(df, class)=="numeric")]))``` process the same way? I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer :). It should work too, did you change variable names correctly? Can't check it, since I am on my phone

Comment: I selected your answer:). Apparently I didn't label the median variable correctly.                                                                                                         ``` result <- data.frame(colMeans(df[which(sapply(df, class)=="numeric")]))
    result2 <- data.frame(colMedians(df[which(sapply(df, class)=="numeric")]))
    colnames(result)[1] <- "result"
    colnames(result2)[2] <- "result2"
    result
    result2                                                                                                         ``` Have a nice evening.

Comment: Gonna do that tomorrow

Comment: Good morning.
`result <- data.frame(colMedians(as.matrix(df[which(sapply(df, class)=="numeric")])))`
This works => colMedians function only accepts a matrix as input, while dplyr returns a data.frame

Comment: Excellent.  I also ran used the dplyr method as well to augment my understanding of Shiny. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the last function.

```
colMeans(df[,which(sapply(df, class) !="date","date1","group")])
```

This code will apply the function to all columns which are not of class xy. `"date"` or `"group"` are column names.

`ColMeans` also produces a numeric vector, which will result in an error, because `DT` can only display a matrix or a data.frame. I provided you a code with creates a dataframe. But in generell I would think about using `dplyr` to create your result. It is much easier.

Here is a solution that works, however you have to change the dateinputs, since the predefined selection creates a data.frame with 0 rows.

```
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

### Generate a dataset ###
start_date <- as.Date('2018-01-01')  
end_date <- as.Date('2019-05-10')   
set.seed(1984)
date1 <- as.Date(sample( as.numeric(start_date): as.numeric(end_date), 988, 
                         replace = T), origin = '1970-01-01')
group <- rep(letters[1:26], each = 38)
x1 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x2 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x3 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x4 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
x5 <- runif(n = 988, min = 3.26, max = 10)
latitude <- runif(988,40.75042,50.75042)
longitude <- runif(988,-73.98928,-63.98928)

dataframe <- cbind(data.frame(date1,group,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,latitude,longitude))

df10 <- cbind(data.frame(date1,group,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5))
dataframe$date <- ymd(dataframe$date1)
df10$date <- ymd(df10$date1)


dataframe$defectrateLvl <- cut(dataframe$x1, 
                               c(3.26,6,100), include.lowest = T,
                               labels = c('3.26-6x','6x+')) 
beatCol <- colorFactor(palette = c('yellow', 'red'), dataframe$defectrateLvl)


ui <- fluidPage(
    dateInput(inputId = "date", label="Select a date", value = "2019-03-01", min = "2018-01-01", max = "2019-05-10",
              format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month",
              language = "en", width = NULL),
    leafletOutput("map"),
    fluidRow(
        dateRangeInput("daterange","Date range:",start=Sys.Date()-10, end=Sys.Date() -1),
        DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")
    )
)

server <- shinyServer(function (input, output,session) {
    dailyData <- reactive(dataframe[dataframe$date == format(input$date, '%Y/%m/%d'), ] )
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        dataframe <- dailyData()  # Added this in attempt to integrate
        dataframe %>% leaflet() %>% 
            setView(lng = -73.98928, lat = 40.75042, zoom = 10) %>%
            addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
            addCircleMarkers(
                lng=~dataframe$longitude, # Longitude coordinates
                lat=~dataframe$latitude, # Latitude coordinates
                #radius=~defectrateLvl, # Total count
                popup =~ dataframe$group,
                color = ~beatCol(dataframe$defectrateLvl),
                fillOpacity=0.5 # Circle Fill Opacity
            )
    })  

    dataset <- reactive({df10 })

    output$tbl <-DT::renderDataTable({
        df <- dataset()

        df <- df %>% 
            group_by(group) %>% 
            filter(date > input$daterange[1],
                   date < input$daterange[2])
        #sapply(Filter(is.numeric, df6), mean)
        result <- data.frame(colMeans(df[which(sapply(df, class)=="numeric")]))
        colnames(result)[1] <- "Result"
        result
        #colMeans(df[,which(sapply(df, class) !="date","date1","group")])
    })

})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```